# Auto scale legend on ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a large number of data points using ggplot2 in R. I am trying to plot the 3-D data (i.e eastings, northings and elevations). What I am trying to achieve is when I change the xlimits or `scale_x_continuous` then the legend will be automatically updated to the current extent.

For example, the syntax I am using in as follows:

The data can be found on the following location: https://www.dropbox.com/s/64x9374y2zip6f7/data-river.csv

```
p <- ggplot(data1,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z),size=1)+geom_point()
p
```

The output I got is as follows:

[image]

Then I use the following syntax to change the x and y axis limits:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data1,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z),size=1)+geom_point()+scale_x_continuous(limits = c(470000,472500))+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(3704000,3706000))
p1
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

As, we can see the extents are changed in both figures, however, the legend scale doesn't change. I don't know how to change the legend with auto scale view. I don't whether it is possible in ggplot or not.

I would also appreciate if someone could point how to make the graph with multiple colors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset() your data to only include the region you want to plot,

```
p1 %+% subset(data1, x < 472500 & x > 470000 & y < 3706000 & y > 3704000)
```

and for the colours, have a look at `?scale_colour_gradientn` for instance.